# ¿Cómo reemplazar varios NA con sus valores más cercanos temporalmente?

Tags: r

Necesito cambiar los `NA` de un data frame con los últimos valores que dicha variable toma en el tiempo.

Es un base de participación de empresas en distintas zonas, ordenadas por fecha. Por lo tanto las variables son las siguientes:

```
fecha <- c("2009-01-01", "2009-01-01", "2009-02-01", "2009-02-01", "2017-08-01", "2017-08-01", "2017-09-01", "2017-09-01")
empresa <-  c("A", "B", NA, NA, "C", "D", NA, NA )
area <-  c("zona 1", "zona 1", "zona 1", "zona 1", "zona 2", "zona 2", "zona 2", "zona 2"  )
participacion <-  c(0.5, 0.5, NA, NA, 0.5, 0.5, NA, NA)

DF <- data.frame(fecha, empresa, area, participacion)

     fecha empresa   area participacion
1 2009-01-01       A zona 1           0.5
2 2009-01-01       B zona 1           0.5
3 2009-02-01    <NA> zona 1            NA
4 2009-02-01    <NA> zona 1            NA
5 2017-08-01       C zona 2           0.5
6 2017-08-01       D zona 2           0.5
7 2017-09-01    <NA> zona 2            NA
8 2017-09-01    <NA> zona 2            NA
```

Necesitaría reemplazar los valores NA de "empresa" y "participacion" por los últimos valores que fueron tomando en el tiempo. Por ejemplo, para febrero de 2009 necesito que las empresas de la zona 1 sean nuevamente A y B (con su respectiva participación); lo mismo con los NA de la zona 2: necesito que sean C y D septiembre de 2017.

Es decir, debería llegar al siguiente resultado:

```
fecha empresa   area participacion
    1 2009-01-01       A zona 1           0.5
    2 2009-01-01       B zona 1           0.5
    3 2009-02-01       A zona 1            NA
    4 2009-02-01       B zona 1            NA
    5 2017-08-01       C zona 2           0.5
    6 2017-08-01       D zona 2           0.5
    7 2017-09-01       C zona 2            NA
    8 2017-09-01       D zona 2            NA
```

Cómo podría resolverlo?

Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma podría ser, combinando los datos con un determinado orden (los `NA` abajo) con el mismo `data.frame` pero con el orden invertido (los `NA` arriba). Esto con `tidyverse` es bastante sencillo y explicativo.

Armamos primero los dos juegos de datos

```
library("tidyverse")

DF %>% 
  arrange(area, is.na(empresa), desc(fecha)) %>% 
  group_by(area) %>% 
  mutate(nr=row_number()) -> A

DF %>% 
  arrange(area, !is.na(empresa), desc(fecha)) %>% 
  group_by(area) %>% 
  mutate(nr=row_number()) -> B
```

El tema fundamental es el orden distinto de los dos `data.frame` y el numerador `nr` particionado por cada `area`. Si ahora "juntamos" ambos grupos combinándolos por `area` y `nr`, va a quedar mas claro lo que estamos queriendo hacer:

```
A %>% 
  left_join(B, by=c("area", "nr")) %>% 
  select(fecha.x, area, empresa.x, empresa.y, participacion.x, participacion.y)

# A tibble: 8 x 6
# Groups:   area [2]
  fecha.x    area   empresa.x empresa.y participacion.x participacion.y
  <fct>      <fct>  <fct>     <fct>               <dbl>           <dbl>
1 2009-01-01 zona 1 A         NA                    0.5            NA  
2 2009-01-01 zona 1 B         NA                    0.5            NA  
3 2009-02-01 zona 1 NA        A                    NA               0.5
4 2009-02-01 zona 1 NA        B                    NA               0.5
5 2017-08-01 zona 2 C         NA                    0.5            NA  
6 2017-08-01 zona 2 D         NA                    0.5            NA  
7 2017-09-01 zona 2 NA        C                    NA               0.5
8 2017-09-01 zona 2 NA        D                    NA               0.5
```

Y ahora sí, aquellos casos dónde el valor de los datos "a izquierda" (los de `A`) sea `NA`, los reemplazamos con los valores de "la derecha" (los de `B`)

```
A %>% 
  left_join(B, by=c("area", "nr")) %>% 
  mutate(empresa = ifelse(is.na(empresa.x), as.character(empresa.y), as.character(empresa.x)),
         participacion = ifelse(is.na(participacion.x), participacion.y, participacion.x)
         ) %>% 
  select(fecha = fecha.x, 
         empresa,
         area, 
         participacion)

# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   area [2]
  fecha      empresa area   participacion
  <fct>      <chr>   <fct>          <dbl>
1 2009-01-01 A       zona 1           0.5
2 2009-01-01 B       zona 1           0.5
3 2009-02-01 A       zona 1           0.5
4 2009-02-01 B       zona 1           0.5
5 2017-08-01 C       zona 2           0.5
6 2017-08-01 D       zona 2           0.5
7 2017-09-01 C       zona 2           0.5
8 2017-09-01 D       zona 2           0.5
```

Comment: Lamentablemente, dicha función no resuelve mi problema. 
Necesito que los valores de "empresa" y "participacion" se repitan en las distintas fechas. Por ejemplo, para febrero de 2009 necesito que las empresas de la zona 1 sean nuevamente A y B (y no B y C como resulta de la aplicación de tu función). Lo mismo con los NA de la zona 2: necesito que sean C y D (y no unicamente D)

Comment: Te sugiero que agregues este comentario a tu pregunta, por qué cambia bastante la idea original o al menos lo que yo pude interpretar. ¿Siempre vas a tener la misma cantidad de Na como casos no Na? ¿Que pasaría si tienes do na y un solo valor no na?

Comment: @MateoSuster, revisa mi última edición. Saludos.

Comment: Buenísimo, gracias. Me sirvió. 
La pregunta que hacés es muy relevante, dado que es el problema que ahora tengo que resolver: no siempre tengo la misma cantidad de casos NA como casos Non NA. El problema es que el dataset que tengo posee un sólo valor para la variable fecha cuando necesito que dicha fila se repita dos o tres veces, según la cantidad de empresas que participan en el área. O sea, me falta completar la serie con las fechas para luego aplicar el código que escribiste. Me explico?

Comment: @MateoSuster, se entiende, mi respuesta te sirve para "copiar" el patrón de valores No NA en el conjunto de los NA, siempre que los primeros sean más que los segundos, te completará todos los casos.